# When doing multiple unique columns can I give a custom name in laravel 5.6?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, unique-key

Consider the following example:

```
$table->unique(['site_id', 'inventory_items', 'lsd_location_id']);
```

This then throws the error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1059 Identifier
>   name
>   'lsd_location_units_site_id_inventory_items_lsd_location_id_unique' is
>   too long (SQL: alter table `lsd_location_units` add unique
>   `lsd_location_units_site_id_inventory_items_lsd_location_id_unique`(`site_id`,
>   `inventory_items`, `lsd_location_id`))

So the question is: Can I give this a different name and still hold the unique key as it is, so instead of its long name maybe: `sid_ii_lsd_location_unuiqe` or something similar?

**A)** Is that allowed in MYSQL?

**B)** Any way around this issue? As I need all three of these.

**The goal is to say only one inventory_item_id per LSD Location ID Per site.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second argument of `unique` is index key name, try:

```
$table->unique(['site_id', 'inventory_items', 'lsd_location_id'], 'sid_ii_lsd_location_unuiqe');
```

From laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#indexes): 
`Laravel will automatically generate a reasonable index name, but you may pass a second argument to the method to specify the name yourself`

Maximum index name length in MySQL 5.6 is 64 characters ([ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html))